# How can I install the tikz-cd package on Ubuntu?

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, ubuntu, tikz-cd

I have certain codes written in LaTeX with several diagrams in [`tikz-cd`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd). 
I must compile these codes in other computer (with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and when I compile appear this error:

> `tikz-cd.sty` not found

What should I do?

I have already tried downloading the `tikz-cd.sty` file and putting it in `home/myuser/texmf` and it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are not familiar with TDS (TeX Directory Structure),
copy the file tikz-cd.sty in your current working directory.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Thanks, but now a new wrror appears: "I can't find file tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex" but I haven't a file with that name in order to do the same. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: You have to install pgf-tikz.
Please ask ubuntu people.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto I have already installed pgf-tikz. Last time I asked a question regarding a latex package in askubuntu I was asked to post that question here. So..

Comment: Did you create ls-Rs by `sudo mktexlsr`?

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Probably I didn't. I'm not sure what are you talking about (I'm sorry, I'm relatively new in linux/GNU)

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Maybe you could explain to me or indicate to me some place where I could read it? I would really appreciate that

Answer (score 8):

You got two possibilities:

- Use Ubuntu repositories; install `tikz-cd` via the Ubuntu package managing, such as by

  ```
  sudo apt-get install texlive-pictures
  ```
- Download from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd), but then you need to update the PGF package as well! Because `tikz-cd` requires TikZ 3.0, specifically its `quotes` library.

You could consider changing to a current original TeX Live. Staying with Ubuntu's TeX version is pretty safe, as long as you don't add packages with newer dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using TexLive (mine is 2015), you may try the following commands:

```
sudo tlmgr install pgf
sudo tlmgr install tikz-cd
```