# Status of TikZ and outdated TikZ examples

Tags: tikz-pgf

While there's surely many other approaches for drawing geometrical shapes, I've decided to use Latex for this purpose. My search led me to the package TikZ. I've found a nice list of examples at

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

and for my specific purpose, under the geometry area.

From these, the morley triangle is a first step toward what I try to draw but upon compilation I'm being told that tkz-2d doesn't exist, plus a bunch of other warning / error messages such as division by zero. Even opening the example in overleaf leads to a compilation error. 
So I tried to install tkz-2d following

[How can I install the tikz-cd package on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236885/how-can-i-install-the-tikz-cd-package-on-ubuntu)

but none of the proposed solution worked (ubuntu 16.04). At [How to install tkz-2d in TeXLive 2010?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11607/how-to-install-tkz-2d-in-texlive-2010/11614#11614), I find that tkz-2d has been replaced by tkz-euclide, so I go ahead and replace tkz-2d by the newer tkz-euclide. Compilation passes and I have a pdf with the triangle but still with many warnings / errors along the way (mainly `Undefined control sequence`).

I am just at the crossroad of following the TikZ path (preferred) or moving elsewhere, so I have these straightforward questions: is TikZ still alive? Is it worth diving in the 1000+pages pgfmanual.pdf or will it be painful to track the evolution of outdated packages (e.g. tkz-2d) and try to run outdated examples?

Comment: Welcome! Compilation doesn't `pass` if you get errors. Ti*k*Z is very much alive! That is partly why you find outdated examples. But note that the `tkz-` packages are not part of `tikz`. `tkz` is based on `tikz`, but you can use `tikz` without using anything from `tkz` at all. (I've never used `tkz` except occasionally to answer a question, in part because the documentation is not written in a language I understand. But I use `tikz` a lot.)

Comment: You can post links as text and somebody will turn them into links for you. It `is on tex.stackexchange` is not of much help to anybody, I'm afraid. Please also consider adding your code to the question, if you want specific help with it. (I'm not clear whether you want that or not.) I've never heard of `tkz-2d`, by the way, but only `tkz-euclide`. So the latter is not exactly new.

Comment: Examples on http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ can be very helpful. However, very many of them are out of date and their original authors have no way of updating or fixing them. Things seem to get added from time to time, but I'm not clear that existing examples get updated at all. Of course, many answers here may also be out of date, but people do make an effort to update things, especially when somebody reports a problem. The Ti*k*Z manual is very good. You do not need to read all of it. Start with the tutorials in Section 1. Then look up bits you need.

Comment: @cfr, thank you for your comments and feedback. I had inserted the exact link about `tkz-2d` being replaced by `tkz-euclide` but was prevented to post more than 2 links due to my limited reputation. It seems I can add a partial link here so here it is:  tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11607/how-to-install-tkz-2d-in-texlive-2010/11614#11614

Comment: That has lots of invisible characters (not just text). I think I found them all ...

Answer (score 2):

While it appears strange to myself to answer my own question, I think I can positively say that yes, TikZ is very much alive: this book "TikZpour l'impatient" (TikZ for the impatient):

http://math.et.info.free.fr/TikZ/bdd/TikZ-Impatient.pdf

by Tisseau and Duma dates feb. 11th 2017!
Even if one doesn't read french, the examples speak for themselves:
http://math.et.info.free.fr/TikZ/Exemples1.html

They can be downloaded at 
http://math.et.info.free.fr/TikZ/bdd/Exemples.zip

Of the few examples I have tried so far, all compile with no complain. I think I have found my way.